# Error when trying to install sonarqube on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sonarqube

When I try to install sonarqube database I get some errors and database is not created

```
    ActiveRecord::JDBCError: The driver encountered an unknown error: unable to choose type for timestamp from:
    ["datetime2", "datetime"]
            initialize at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:66
           initialize at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:31
      jdbc_connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.1.3/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection_methods.rb:6
                 send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227
       new_connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223
    checkout_new_connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245
    checkout at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188
                 loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519
             checkout at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184
      mon_synchronize at jar:file:/C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191
             checkout at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183
           connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98
  retrieve_connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326
  retrieve_connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123
           connection at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115
           initialize at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440
                   up at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401
              migrate at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383
    upgrade_and_start at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/database_version.rb:62
      automatic_setup at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/config/../lib/database_version.rb:74
               (root) at C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:239
                 load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094
               (root) at file:/C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1
     load_environment at file:/C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25
     load_environment at file:/C:/sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:79
```

i was reading about and looks like database driver is not working alright

Any clues about how can i get this working on SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the locale settings of the database. In my case it helped to set the language for the sonarqube database user to "English". See [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing#Installing-installingDatabaseInstallingtheDatabase).

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I changed the SQL driver (sqljdbc4.jar) to one directly from Microsoft, it looks like my previous driver was third party modified.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21599 this is the original mssql driver form jdbc.

http://www.sezok.de/sonar/sonar.html  this guide was helpful too.

after changing driver, everything works OK